# Repeating error message when trying to receive an integer in a specific range

Tags: c, loops, scanf

The function below receives a range and then asks for an integer. It then must test to make sure it is in that range and is not a char. However, whenever I input any letters it just loops the "ERROR: Value must be between %d and %d inclusive: " msg.

```
void clearStandardInputBuffer(void)//clears character
{
    while (getchar() != '\n')
    {
        ;
    }
}

int getIntFromRange(int lowbound, int upperbound)
{
    int rangenum;
    char newline = 'x';
    while (1)
    {
        scanf(" %d%c", &rangenum, &newline);

        if (rangenum <= upperbound && rangenum >= lowbound && newline == '\n')
        {
            return rangenum;
        }
        else
        {
            if (rangenum > upperbound || rangenum < lowbound) 
            {
                printf("ERROR: Value must be between %d and %d inclusive: ", lowbound,upperbound);
                
            }
            else if (newline != '\n') {
                clearStandardInputBuffer();
                printf("ERROR: Value must be an integer: ");
                
            }
        
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    getIntFromRange(0, 1);
}
```

Looking for any help!

Comment: This code does not compile due to `getIntFromRange(int 0, int 1);`. Delete the int keywords.

Comment: First you need to check the return value from `scanf`.  If the user types something non-numeric, `scanf` will fail, and you can detect it.  But then you have to figure out how to get the non-numeric input off of the input stream, otherwise the next call to `scanf` will fail also.  Perhaps you don't want to use `scanf` at all — it's miserable for this sort of thing.

Comment: Also, you might as well get rid of that `newline` variable — it's probably not going to help.